# Struts2 autocompleter of struts jquery tag not taking another value other then of list after setting forceValidOption to false

Tags: java, jsp, autocomplete, struts2, struts2-jquery

I have a jsp file in which i have a struts **autocompleter** box of **struts jquery plugin**. This box is not taking any other value which is not in the autocomplete list after setting `forceValidOption` to `false`. What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, if you set `selectbox` to `true` than it will not take any other value other than list with. You have to set `selectbox` to `false` with `forceValidOption` to `false`.